# how to import files properly when __init__.py breaks pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pyinstaller

I've worked on a problem with `pyinstaller` and the fix for my issue was to remove the empty `__init__.py` file from my tree, so I don't have that file anymore and everything works as expected. However, now I am adding more files and have a different folder structure:

```
dist
|
+--- rating_service.exe  # created by pyinstaller
service
|
+--- rating_service.py
shared
|
+--- resource_globals.py
```

**Inside rating_service.py, I have tried these imports and get these errors:**

```
from . import shared
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'shared'

```
from .. import shared
```

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

```
import shared
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared'

How can I access my `resource_globals` content in my `rating_service`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not feasible to add any `__init__.py` files, then as a work-around you could do within your `rating_service.py` code file:

```
# -----------------
# rating_service.py
# -----------------
import os
import sys

# Manually add the 'shared' directory to the python search paths
file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
shared_dir = os.path.join(file_dir, '../shared')
sys.path.insert(0, shared_dir)

import resource_globals
```